# List view is not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

Hi I have created a simple application for displaying contents from database to list view, but my list view is not displaying any data I am a beginner  and I need some assistance.

Giving my list view class below

```
public class Show extends Activity {

    //SQLiteDatabase db;
    //Datahelper dh;
    Context context=this;
    Dataclass dc;

    private ListView mainListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show);

        mainListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        //getDetails();
        dc=new Dataclass(this);
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        String message=bundle.getString("MSG");
        List<String> friendlist=dc.getDetails(message);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,friendlist);

        mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        dc.close();
    }
}
```

I have passed data from one activity to this activity using bundle and I have got the data , but no data is retrieved from the database..

giving m y getdetails function from dataclass below

```
public List<String> getDetails(String message) {
    List<String> Friendlist = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM Mytables WHERE Name='" + message + "' ";
    db = dh.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Friendlist.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }
    return Friendlist;
}
```

giving my xml layout for list activity below

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" 
             >

          <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listview"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          </ListView>

          </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: does friendList has contents in it?

Comment: I think friendlist is null in dataclass..

Comment: Hello guys can anybody help me on this question please ??????????????????????????????????

Comment: You r getting listview id wrong  mainListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

Comment: check for ListView id in java and xml.

Comment: can u provide the code of your adapter class?

Answer (score 0):

try set listview's background color to red, see it is NO-CONTENT or DIDN'T DISPLAY.

Comment: It is not because of changing background color, the list is getting empty I think..

Comment: I know that. change background let you see the 'EMPTY LIST' as background color. so you could figure out empty list or list didn't be displayed.

Comment: i saw your xml, that seems ok. guess friendList is empty, too. check message for sql injection error?

Answer (score 0):

From your layout I can see that you don't have an ListView element with id "list" `mainListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);`. Since all the operations you are running assume the existence of this element, probably this is the reason why nothing appears on the screen.

I also suggest that instead of inheriting from Activity you should inherit from ListActivity  and use existing methods to deal with ListView like `getListView()`, `setListAdapter(adapter)` and keep your `ListView` with the default id `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

Comment: Look, stackoverflow isn't the best place to ask "tell me how to do" questions. Take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on the help center to find a way to refine your doubt.